# Can I launch a specific app when android device get physically connected to a specific usb device?

Tags: android, usb, launch

Can I "register" a (already installed) specific app to be launched when android device get physically connected to a specific usb device ?

Eg.
I connect a keyboard (of a certain brand or with a special USBid/class) and it automatically launch a text editor app
I connect an USB soundcard and it launches an audio app.

And "better", is there an autolaunch on Android ? I plug a keyboard+storage device to my smartphone and Android will ask me if I want to install the apk from the storage (or download it from predefined url)
Obviously for security reasons I understand installing the app from the storage will need confirmation by user. But, once the app has been "registered" would it be possible to launch the app automatically without having a confirmation screen ?

I know I could get USB info with android.hardware.usb.usbdevice. My question is more about how I can tell Android to launch this app rather than another when usb device is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could register your app to receive a system broadcast like `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` and make the logic to launch your app when this happens.

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it : in the app manifest (in receiver/intent-filter/action section) you register the event you want to be monitored.
In my case "android.intent.action.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED". 
In my code, I need to implement a subclass of BroadcastReceiver and the onReceive(Context, Intent) method.
This will run in the background process of the app and will be waken up by the OS when the event occurs.
Then I'll have to take the UI of my app to the foreground. I need to work on the BG/UI aspect of it (never done Android dev before) but at least it looks it can be done.

Comment: hey @frenchone can you provide a sample for your broadcast receiver?

Comment: @mohas, It didn't go further than my previous comment. No code was ever produced. Sorry.

Comment: what I went for at the end was registering for `<action
                    android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />`  intent and with `<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />` then when the device is attached `resume` event is called even when your app is in the foreground, if your pid and vid is correct android will launch your app when device is attached